# Why wont my simple python adding calculator work?

Tags: python

Hello I was wondering why my code for an adding calculator wasn't working, I am new to python and programing in general, I am using python 3.4.1.Heres the code:

```
def add(x, y):
    """This function will add two numbers"""

    return x + y


number1 = int(input("pick a number: "))

number2 = int(input("pick another number: "))

choice = input
choice2 = input 
if choice == '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10':
    print (number1,"+",number2, "=", add(number1,number2))

if choice2 == '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10':
    print (number1,"+",number2, "=", add(number1,number2))
```

EDIT: thank you everyone for the help I figured it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want the user to input two numbers, then you validate that both of those numbers are between 1 and 10, and if they are, you output the addition string.

In that case: The line `int(input("pick a number: "))` already guarantees that the input will be a number. The function `int` turns the input into a number.

So all that's left is to check that both inputs are between 1 and 10.

```
def add(x, y):
    """This function will add two numbers"""
    return x + y

number1 = int(raw_input("pick a number: "))

number2 = int(raw_input("pick another number: "))

if 1 <= number1 <= 10 and 1 <= number2 <= 10:
    print (number1,"+",number2, "=", add(number1,number2))
```

If you really want to be nice to the user, you can validate their input as you go along:

```
number1 = -1
while not 1 <= number1 <= 10:
  number1 = int(raw_input("pick a number: "))

number2 = -1
while not 1 <= number2 <= 10:
  number2 = int(raw_input("pick another number: "))

print (number1,"+",number2, "=", add(number1,number2))
```

Comment: I'm on python 2.7.6 on this machine. Feel free to change `raw_input` back to `input`.

Answer (score 1):

Here,`input` is not defined, so it will throw an error `input undefined`

```
choice = input
choice2 = input
```

You can't do it this way:

```
if choice == '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10':
    print (number1,"+",number2, "=", add(number1,number2))

if choice2 == '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10':
    print (number1,"+",number2, "=", add(number1,number2))
```

The correct way to do it would be:

```
if int(choice) <= 10:
    # do something
```

This is how you should do it, if you want to limit the numbers from `1` to `10`.

```
num1 = int(input("Pick a number: "))
num2 = int(input("Pick another number: "))

if num1 <= 10 and num2 <= 10:
    print(str(num1) + "+" + str(num2) "=", str(sum([num1, num2])))
else:
    print("The number you entered is greater than 10")
```

If you are not familiar with the `sum()` function,`sum([num1, num2])` returns the sum of num1 and num2.

And this is for if you want to put no limit:

```
num1 = int(input("Pick a number: "))
num2 = int(input("Pick another number: "))

print("The sum of " + num1 + "and " + num2 + "is: " + str(sum([num1 + num2])))
```

Comment: I tried that way and I got a syntax error, here is my code now

Comment: `def add(x, y):
 """This function will add two numbers"""

 return x + y
 
numbers = range(1,11)

num1 = int(input("pick a number: "))
num2 = int(input("pick another number: "))

if num1 in numbers and num2 in numbers:    # If the input num1 is in the list numbers, then do the following, else execute the else section.
    print (str(num1) + "+" + str(num2) "=", sum([num1, num2]))
else:
    print ("The number you entered is greater than 10")`

Comment: I have edited my answer, try it now. It should work.

Comment: And you don't need the `add(x, y)` function anymore as you can get the same result using `sum([x, y])`. Even if you have say `x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`, you can simply do `sum(x)` and it will return the sum of all the numbers in list `x`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `'a' 'b'` is the same as `'ab'`.

Thus, your code is asking for strings, converting them to integers, then asking for another two strings, which it compares to `'12345678910'`. Unless you enter `'12345678910'` for one of them, nothing happens.

Unfortunately, aside from that, your question is a bit vague. If you describe what exactly the program is supposed to do ("a calculator" is not nearly specific enough), we might help you work out how to do it.

EDIT: too much Ruby, didn't even notice the `choice = input` thing. See rroszkowiak's answer.

Comment: i just want it to add two numbers

Comment: If you want it to add the numbers in `number1` and `number2`, what are `choice` and `choice2` for?

Comment: `def add(x, y):
 """This function will add two numbers"""

 return x + y
 

number1 = int(input("pick a number: "))

number2 = int(input("pick another number: "))


if number1 == '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10':
 print (number1,"+",number2, "=", add(number1,number2))
  
if number2 == '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10':
 print (number1,"+",number2, "=", add(number1,number2))`

Comment: When adding code, especially in Python, please edit your original question. Python without line breaks and indentation is near-impossible to read correctly.

Comment: But as I said, `number == '1' '2'...` is not what you want, `number in [1, 2, ...]` is. Or even better `number in range(1, 11)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a calculator where you choose any two numbers and then choose what you want to do to them:

```
num_1 = int(raw_input("Enter Your First Number"))
num_2 = int(raw_input("Enter Your Second Number"))
sum_1 = raw_input("Choose Sum (+ - / or *)")

if sum_1 == "+":
  print num_1, "+", num_2, "=", num_1 + num_2
elif sum_1 == "-":
  print num_1, "-", num_2, "=", num_1 - num_2
elif sum_1 == "/":
  print num_1, "/", num_2, "=", num_1 / num_2
elif sum_1 == "*":
  print num_1, "*", num_2, "=", num_1 * num_2
else:
  print "Numbers or Sum Not Recognised"
```